# Exception while deployement of AXIS2 in Websphere7.0

Tags: apache-axis, websphere-7

I was deployed the AXIS2.WAR file in the Websphere7 App.Server.
When i am accessing the AXIS Admin console I am getting This Exception
Can any one give me an Idea whats going wrong?

This is Exception Log

The ping-1.6.2.jar module, which is not valid, caused org.apache.axis2.ping.PingMessageReceiver incompatible with org.apache.axis2.engine.MessageReceiver
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.ping.PingMessageReceiver incompatible with org.apache.axis2.engine.MessageReceiver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.readModuleArchive(ArchiveReader.java:527)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadClassPathModules(RepositoryListener.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:71)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.ping.PingMessageReceiver incompatible with org.apache.axis2.engine.MessageReceiver
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.loadMessageReceiver(DescriptionBuilder.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.processOperations(ModuleBuilder.java:306)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.populateModule(ModuleBuilder.java:220)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.readModuleArchive(ArchiveReader.java:514)
    ... 32 more
[9/12/12 11:17:09:377 GMT+05:30] 00000029 SystemOut     O [INFO] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
[9/12/12 11:17:09:378 GMT+05:30] 00000029 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0100E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet AxisServlet in application axis2_war: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:462)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:591)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageModule(AxisConfiguration.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageGlobalModules(AxisConfiguration.java:705)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.engageModules(DeploymentEngine.java:831)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.engageGlobalModules(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:300)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    ... 22 more

[9/12/12 11:17:09:380 GMT+05:30] 00000029 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[AxisServlet]: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageModule(AxisConfiguration.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageGlobalModules(AxisConfiguration.java:705)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.engageModules(DeploymentEngine.java:831)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.engageGlobalModules(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:300)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:165)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:628)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

[9/12/12 11:17:09:388 GMT+05:30] 00000029 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [axis2_war] [/axis2] [/axis2-web/Error

Thanks
Ramakrishna Chowdary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessary steps to deploy Axis2 on WebSphere 7.0 are given in the following document:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html#WebSphere

Comment: HI Thanks for you response I have done all the changes but its not working.I am getting same exception

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the axis2.xml file from WEB-INF/conf directory. it will works.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got downvoted. It solved the described problem in my case. The solution was to delete the local axis2.xml, thus taking WebSphere's own axis2.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Add into below lines into your axis2.xml inside conf folder:
transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener"

parameter name="port">90809443

Save and restart the server and check.

Answer (score -1):

follow the complete steps from:
http://zacktutorials.blogspot.in/2014/04/axis2-installation-in-websphere-80-to.html

then delete the axis2.xml from conf folder.
It works for me